# remove one IP from linux route cache programatically

Tags: c, linux, caching, routes, iptables

I made a back-end server which redirects users who abuse the main server (via too many invalid webpage requests in a short time) to another port so that the load on the server will be slightly less.

I then in my program via a `exec()` issue this command to block the IP from regular service:

```
iptables -t nat -I <tableforport> -p tcp --src <offending ip> -j REDIRECT --to-port <port of my server>
```

The problem is when I test this using an actual 2-computer setup where one is the client spamming the server (I'm actually holding F5 down for a few minutes to test), The internal port redirection doesn't seem to kick in right away. If I pause from holding F5 down for a few minutes then try again, then the internal redirection works and the blocking message from my server software works.

I feel this is due to linux (which the server runs on) caching remote IP address entries along with its ports along with other instructions causing the new iptables rules (like the one above) to be skipped until the routing cache is flushed for that IP.

In linux, I can easily flush the routing cache for each IP version via:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipvn/route/flush
```

where n in ipvn is either a 4 or 6.

The problem with that is if I execute it, then all the good IP's in cache will be flushed which in turn creates a slower experience for all. I only want to create a bad experience to potential hackers.

How do I go about removing only one IP address from the route cache so that when I add a redirection rule to iptables (like above), the redirection takes place right away the moment the client refreshes the page (not several refreshes, seconds or minutes later)?

Once I get an answer, I want to be able to make a C program out of it after which I can probably figure out myself.

Comment: possible because some other rule? check http://serverfault.com/questions/196702/how-long-does-it-take-for-an-iptables-rule-to-apply

Comment: The route cache is different from iptables. Its populated automatically with ip addresses that access the server. The entries in iptables must be entered in by a user or program

Comment: nat is done before routing, your issue more like the connected tcp connectoin will use some other rule.